# Obtain days between dates in array of different ID's

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, nested-if

I would like to get the days and total days between each date for only the same row IDs.
So far, found some code that can help me get the days between each date and separately determine if each current row is the same or different from the previous row. I'm unable to join both in order to only get the corresponding days between each date corresponding to the same ID.
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngIIc.png)

Code inside C2:

```
={"Days Since Previous Payment";ArrayFormula(IFNA(vlookup(row(A3:A),{query(filter(row(A3:A),B3:B>0),"Select * offset 1",0),filter(if({filter(A3:A,B3:B>0);0}*{0;filter(A3:A,B3:B>0)},{filter(A3:A,B3:B>0);0}-{0;filter(A3:A,B3:B>0)},),if({filter(A3:A,B3:B>0);0}*{0;filter(A3:A,B3:B>0)},{filter(A3:A,B3:B>0);0}-{0;filter(A3:A,B3:B>0)},)<>"")},2,0)))}
```

Code inside E3 and on until E18:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()))<>INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()-1)),INDIRECT("B"&(ROW())),INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()-1))))
```

Just in case, here is the dummy page:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HSZKq5JhrHRtl-XPQ6QJF1wNX4e2_5jmyjNK2pPZpDM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's not how this site works. We don't follow links somewhere else to get details needed for your question. Please provide the relevant information here, in your question itself. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Sorry about that @KenWhite, been searching for an answer and have seen other users add spreadsheets links in order to get a better insight to respond to answers. 
Do you recommend adding screenshots instead?

Comment: No, I recommend that you add sample data in the form of a table, and include your code as text that is properly formatted for readability, as required in the [help/on-topic] guidelines, which say that *all relevant information must be here in the question itself*. Code and data are both text, not images or links. You don't edit that data or code using an image editor - you use your keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A4:A19-A3:A18)
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,{0; IF(A4:A1000-A3:A999<0, 0, A4:A1000-A3:A999)}))
```

[image]

Comment: So cool @player0 , thanx for your help. While I was going through each line, noticed that K7 shows number 69 wich is the subrstraction of G7 and G6, thing is, K7 and K6 have different IDs, value should be cero...any thoughts? By the way could this be added to a query as a column value?

Comment: @kueyiar try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,IF(B4:B1000=B3:B999, {0; IF(A4:A1000-A3:A999<0, 0, A4:A1000-A3:A999)}, 0)))` and yes it could

Comment: Nice touch on the evaluation for B Column @player0. Strange thing is that now, the last row on the IDs sequence ends up in a cero before changing to the new ID. Could additional tinkering be added to it, please =)

Comment: I believe I may have roughed it out. Used your code and added **=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,{0; IF(A4:A-A3:A<0, 0, if(B4:B<>B3:B,0,A4:A-A3:A))}))** in order to validate last row of series. Added it under column M, went through the whole series and it's looking good. Wouldn't have gotten to the answer without your help. Really appreciate it @player0, Thanx for your help!

Comment: Can't quite figure out how to add this condition to the query...Current query that obtains column A and B runs goes by: **=query({indirect(dataImportsLastRowFull)},"select Col1,Col2  where Col2 like 'B%' order by Col2, Col1 asc",0)**. Would really appreciate your help =)

Comment: where exactly you ant to add it?

Comment: I would like for the result to be a third column on the query. =)

Comment: try: `=index(query({indirect(dataImportsLastRowFull!3:999), IF(A3:A="",,{0; IF(A4:A-A3:A<0, 0, if(B4:B<>B3:B,0,A4:A-A3:A))})}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col2 like 'B%' order by Col2, Col1 asc",0))`

Comment: Tried your suggestion, got a "circular dependency detected" error. Guess it can't refer to itself...Any other thoughts?

Comment: @kueyiar can you share a copy of your sheet with that error?

Comment: just added  **Sheet3** with data and structure as requested ! =)

Comment: see A3 in your Sheet3 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k9p3.png

Comment: dude, that's so crazy! Yet so awesome! Can't thank you enough! Will have to study the logic on it though, LOL! 
How would I go about using a _where_ clause in order to filter the desired IDs from column B corresponding to the dataImports sheet?

Comment: wrap it all into QUERY() and use where on Col2 as you need

Comment: Thank you Soooooo Much! Hopefully won't run into any more hiccups on the sheets I'm working on, but if I do, I know just the PRO to contact! Cheers!